# update useState() array when element is modified REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fairly new to react to please bare with me. I am creating a todo application that just keeps tracks of tasks.

**Issue:**

the state called `[tasks, setTasks] = useState([])` does update when i try to edit a task within the `tasks` state.

For example lets say `tasks` contains `["make bed", "fold cloths"]` and I wanted to update "fold cloths" to "fold clothes and put away". When I use `setTasks` the state does not update.

The modification of the state happens in the `modifyTask` function.

**Here is my code:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

// Imported Components below
import CurrentTasks from "./CurrentTasks";

function InputTask() {
  // Initial array for storing list items
  // Tracking state of input box
  const [task, setTask] = useState("");
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks") || "[]")
  );

  function deleteTask(index) {
    function checkIndex(task, i) {
      if (i !== index) {
        return task;
      }
    }
    setTasks(prev => prev.filter(checkIndex));
  }

  function modifyTask(index) {
    let editedTask = prompt("Please edit task here..", tasks[index]);
    function editTask(task, i) {
      if (i === index) {
        task = editedTask;
      }
      console.log(task);
      return task;
    }
    setTasks(prev => prev.filter(editTask));
  }

  function handleAddTask() {
    setTasks(prev => prev.concat(task));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // Saves every time tasks state changes
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));
    console.log("Tasks: " + tasks);
    setTask("");
  }, [tasks]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="input-group mt-4">
        <input
          type="text"
          value={task}
          onChange={e => setTask(e.target.value)}
          className="form-control form-control-lg"
          placeholder="Write task here..."
        />
        <div className="input-group-append">
          <button onClick={handleAddTask} className="btn btn-outline-secondary">
            Add
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <CurrentTasks
        allTasks={tasks}
        deleteTask={deleteTask}
        modifyTask={modifyTask}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default InputTask;
```

**What I think is happening**

-> My theory is that the state only updates when the number of elements within the array changes. If thats the case is there an elegant way of doing so?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change your modify function to use `map` instead of `filter`, as `filter` doesn't change the array outside of removing elements. Map takes the returned values and creates a new array from them.

```
  function modifyTask(index) {
    let editedTask = prompt("Please edit task here..", tasks[index]);
    function editTask(task, i) {
      if (i === index) {
        task = editedTask;
      }
      console.log(task);
      return task;
    }
    setTasks(prev => prev.map(editTask));
  }
```